# regionmask clipping data at border

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to use regionmask to show only a specific region for data. The data without the mask is shown:

[image]

If I apply a mask to the data using the code:

```
mercator = ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=-99.6,min_latitude=35,max_latitude=50)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=mercator)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS,linestyle=':')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES,alpha=0.5)

mask = regionmask.defined_regions.natural_earth_v5_0_0.us_states_50.mask(dataset)
data_CNA = dataset.where((x == self.masks['CO']))
preplot = ax.contourf(data_CNA[variable].lon,data_CNA[variable].lat,data_CNA[variable].values,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I get the plot:

[image]

The regionmask is clipping the data on the west and north border. I wonder if its a projection issue but I'm not sure. How can I get the data to touch the regionmask border.

Update:

I applied a scatter of the grid points to look at the edges:
[image]

It looks like the missing edges are caused by the point not being included by the mask, which I guess, is expected. So now the question is, is there a way to mask the region by filling it in or another method that would keep the contours at the edges.

Comment: Can you try to add the state borders from another source, instead of cfeature?

Comment: Sure, any recommendations?